# Chrome Dev Tools: tooltips are not displaying correctly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I hover over the inspect tool or over the styles.css link in the styles tab, the tooltip is not displaying correctly. It is too far to the right and cut off. I have tried un-installing and re-installing Chrome. I have tried disabling all my extensions. I can't figure out what's causing this. Is this just a bug? I have already submitted this to the Google Chrome help. I am running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and Chrome Version 67.0.3396.62.
Screenshot of dev tools
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I finally solved this by turning off "Use hardware acceleration when available" in my Chrome settings.

Comment: This kinda work... I have to highlight variables and then hover over them to see the values. Also I still don't have syntax highlighting.. I tested this for debugging `typescript` files.

Comment: Thanks, works for win 10 + chrome 79 (using this version because of mobile inspector is busted on version 80). Remember to relaunch chrome after changing that setting

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in version 79. You have to update your Google Chrome to version 80+.